# Insert 2 rows to sqlite when using SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() method

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Code for creating the Database:

```
private static final String DB_CREATE =
                            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                    COLUMN_ITEM +" TEXT NOT NULL " +
                            ");";
```

I'm using the following code but it only inserts the last value (`Swipe me to delete`) but not the first (`Click me to edit`) , so how should I proceed to insert 2 rows?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ITEM, "Click me to edit");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ITEM, "Swipe me to delete");

    database.insert(
            TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            contentValues
    );
}
```

Find out how to solve it so I'm leaving the answer below but if anyone knows how to use ContentValues to insert more than 1 row I would appreciate the answer.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found how to solve it using execSQL:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_NAME  + " VALUES(null, 'Click me to edit');");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_NAME  + " VALUES(null, 'Swipe me to erase');");

    }
```

Comment: you can also achieve same by calling database.insert for each value

Answer (score 2):

`insert()` inserts a single row with the values in the `ContentValues` object.

To get two rows, you need to call `insert()` twice, with different `ContentValues`:

```
contentValues.put(COLUMN_ITEM, "Click me to edit");
database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
contentValues.put(COLUMN_ITEM, "Swipe me to delete");
database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

Comment: is there any method from database.*() to call to insert more than just 1 value when using contentValues?

Comment: No. If you need it, it's trivial to write your own helper function.